# Is there a way to determine if LC_CTYPE is set in C?

Tags: c, locale, setlocale

Using C, is there a way to find out if LC_CTYPE is set? I am rewriting printf and my %lc needs to work differently depending on if the locale is set.

Answer (score 1):

`LC_CTYPE` is an environment variable. You can use any of the normal methods of accessing environment variables, which differ based on platform. For example, POSIX's third `envp` argument to `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp);
```

or the standard C89 `getenv()` function:

```
char *getenv(const char *name);
```

For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char const *get_lc_ctype()
{
    return getenv("LC_CTYPE");
}
```

Be careful not to modify strings returned by `getenv(3)`, that is undefined behaviour. If you want to set `LC_CTYPE`, you should use the (POSIX-standardised but not C-standardised) `setenv(3)`:

```
int set_lc_ctype(char const *new)
{
    return setenv("LC_CTYPE", new, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic way is to use 'setlocale()'.
From the man page:

> If  locale  is  an  empty  string, "", each part of the locale that should be modified is set according to the
>          environment variables.

Thus, you get LC_TYPE by

```
#include <locale.h>
// ...
char* lc_type= setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
```